# Какие есть методы защиты os x приложения от воровства?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

Занимаюсь разработкой ios приложений. Сама по себе ios не позволяет установить приложение которое было куплено не тобой, если конечно система не джейлбрейкнута.

При этом в **OS X** можно скачать приложение с торрента и свободно установить.

**Вопрос** к OS X разработчикам - какие есть методы защиты приложения от воровства и какие наиболее эффективны? Я понимаю что на любую программу есть кейген, значит универсального метода нет, тем не менее хотелось бы узнать все возможные способы.

P.S. Приложение собираюсь распространять вне Mac Appstore, но при этом приложение будет подписано девелоперским сертификатом.

Answer (score 2):

Например как это делает JetBrains.
Человек заводит аккаунт у вас на сервере, там к его аккаунту цепляется ключ на купленные продукты. Соответственно при первом запуске софтина привязывается к нужному аккаунту на сервере и при каждом запуске проверяет, не краденая ли она.

Но вообще, есть мнение, что вопрос защиты софта от копирования имеет смысл только для уже коммерчески успешного и востребованного софта. А если он уже коммерчески успешен, то деньги для найма разработчиков, которые будут пилить суперзащиту, есть.